# Converting from xml to xlsl with minidom and xml2xlsx doesnt work

Tags: python, xml, file, minidom

I am trying to convert multiple XML files to xlsl with Python and I found a library called xml2xlsx, which could help me do that! My idea was to open the XML file with the minidom library, save it in a variable and then write it to an xlsx file. I have the written so far the following code:

```
from xml2xlsx import xml2xlsx
from xml.dom import minidom
template = open('file.xml','r')
xmldoc = minidom.parse(template)
template.close()

f = open('test.xlsx', 'wb')
f.write(xml2xlsx(template))
f.close()
```

The problem is that when running it I get an error saying:

```
PS C:\Users\andri\PythonProjects\mypyth> py toexcel.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "toexcel.py", line 8, in <module>
    f.write(xml2xlsx(template))
  File "C:\Users\andri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\xml2xlsx\__init__.py", line 237, in xml2xlsx
    return etree.XML(xml, parser, )
  File "src\lxml\etree.pyx", line 3201, in lxml.etree.XML
  File "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 1876, in lxml.etree._parseMemoryDocument
ValueError: can only parse strings
```

I understand that probably the xml2xlsx writter can only write strings(I am not sure if it correct tho) but I dont understand how to fix it. Could someone please help me? I appreciate any help you can provide

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may have been trying to follow this example [from the README](https://github.com/pkaczynski/xml2xlsx#example):

> ```py
> from xml2xlsx import xml2xlsx
> template = '<sheet title="test"></sheet>'
> f = open('test.xlsx', 'wb')
> f.write(xml2xlsx(template))
> f.close()
> ```

As you can see, `template` is a `str` here. Whereas in your example, `template` is a [`Document`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.dom.minidom.html#xml.dom.minidom.parse).

You can either convert this back to an xml string through [`Node.to_xml`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.dom.minidom.html#xml.dom.minidom.Node.toxml):

```py
from xml2xlsx import xml2xlsx
from xml.dom import minidom

with open('file.xml') as xml_file:
    template = minidom.parse(xml_file)

with open('test.xlsx', 'wb') as xlsx_file:
    xlsx_file.write(xml2xlsx(template.to_xml()))
```

or just skip the `minidom` step altogether:

```py
from xml2xlsx import xml2xlsx

with open('file.xml') as xml_file:
    template = xml_file.read()

with open('test.xlsx', 'wb') as xlsx_file:
    xlsx_file.write(xml2xlsx(template))
```